# Component's configuration: Save multiple values

Tags: joomla-3.4, jform, form-fields-types, fields

I would like to do this in my config.xml of my component:

```
    <field  name="allowedfiletypes" 
            type="list" 
            multiple="true"
            label="COM_BESTIA_FIELD_ALLOWEDFILETYPES"
            description="COM_BESTIA_FIELD_ALLOWEDFILETYPES_DESC">
            <option value="png">PNG</option>
            <option value="jpeg">JPEG</option>
            <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
            <option value="gif">GIF</option>
            <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
            <option value="zip">ZIP</option>                                                
    </field>
```

Unfortunately the com_config does not save multiple values here. If I do not use `multiple=true` it works (but only saves one value as you can see here http://d.pr/1fulC).

With Field type "user group" the multiple-tag works without problems.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: This exact code works for me on Joomla! 3.4.1. See [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/t8sz21i8h/). This is after saving, not selected.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked too much into `multiple="true"` but an alternative could be using a text box and separating each value with a comma, like so:

```
<field name="allowedfiletypes" 
       type="text" 
       label="COM_BESTIA_FIELD_ALLOWEDFILETYPES"
       description="COM_BESTIA_FIELD_ALLOWEDFILETYPES_DESC"
       default="png,jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf,zip" />
```

You could then if you like save the value as 1 json encoded string

Comment: Hm, okay. That would be possible. But isn't it planned for future? Because userlist-type is already able to save multiple values.